# Improving performance of a routine in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia

Could anyone help me improve this little code?

```
for i=1:320000
  for j=1:2000
    var1=dot(array[:,i],array[:,j])/320000
  end
end
```

The issue is that in C# the same code runs about 30 seconds, while the code above in Julia lasts 10 minutes!!. I'have tried using another for loop instead of the dot function. Any help will be appreciated.

Yes, I have tried it in a function, also I have tried a simple computation like this

```
for i=1:320000
  for j=1:200
    i*j
  end 
end
```

This is pretty fast, but if I call the array, say

```
for i=1:320000
 for j=1:200
   array[j]
 end
end
```

It is weird, I now, but again it lasts at least 2 minutes, so it seems the issue is the calling of the array, What do you think ?

Comment: That code doesn't make too much sense in isolation, can you post a more complete code snippet?

Comment: It also appears to be missing a closing parenthesis for the `dot` function...

Answer (score 1):

Are you running that from inside a function? See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/performance-tips/